# Clone-equivalent of fork?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'd like to use the namespacing features of the `clone` function. Reading the manpage, it seems like `clone` has lots of intricate details I need to worry about.

Is there an equivalent `clone` invocation to good ol' `fork()`?

I'm already familiar with `fork`, and believe that if I have a starting point in `clone`, I can add flags and options from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this will work, but I'm not entirely certain about some of the pointer arguments.

```
pid_t child = clone( child_f, child_stack, 
           /* int flags                */     SIGCHLD, 
           /* argument to child_f      */     NULL,
           /* pid_t *pid               */     NULL,
           /* struct usr_desc * tls    */     NULL,
           /* pid_t *ctid              */     NULL );
```

In the flags parameter the lower byte of it is used to specify which signal to send to notify the parent of the thread doing things like dying or stopping.  I believe that all of the actual flags turn on switches which are different from `fork`.  Looking at the kernel code suggests this is the case.

If you really want to get something close to `fork` you may want to call `sys_clone` which does not take function pointer and instead returns twice like `fork`.

Comment: I went code-diving because I still didn't feel comfortable, but it looks like you're right. What I found is that `clone` is a very thin wrapper around `sys_clone`, mostly just doing what's necessary to call `fn` on the new stack. `sys_clone` actually returns like `fork`, but cannot be called directly, because it's signature differs per architecture. `fork` is actually rather fat: it executes callbacks, does misc cleanup, but basically uses only SIGCHLD. (I suppose there's nothing I can do to emulate the `fork`-extras.)

Answer (score 1):

You could fork a normal child process using fork(), then use unshare() to create a new namespace.

Namespaces are a bit weird, I can't see a lot of use-cases for them.

Comment: It looks like `unshare` only supports a small subset of the `clone` flags. For example, I want to use `CLONE_NEWNET`, and it returns `EINVAL`.

Answer (score 0):

clone() is used to create a thread.  The big difference between clone() and fork() is that clone() is meant to execute starting at a separate entry point - a function, whereas fork() just continues on down from  the same point in the code from where was invoked.  int (*fn)(void *) in the manpage definition is the function, which on exit returns an int, the exit status.

The closest call to clone is pthread_create() which is essentially a wrapper for clone().
This does not get you a way to get fork() behavior.

Comment: Good point. I'm not too concerned about the `fn` vs. `return` difference between `clone` and `fork`. My aim is understanding how to get the same subprocess characteristics (and what they are). In any case, `pthread_create` doesn't offer me the namespacing flags.